# Spring boot && Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

Please help to correct me of this argument call function with postgresql with spring boot

Postgres

```
select * from func_get_available_room('20191120','20191122',array[1,2],1);
```

Spring boot

```
@Select("select * from func_get_available_room(#{in},#{out},ARRAY[ #{type}::Integer ],#{room})")
```

List getAvailableRoom(String in, String out, Integer type , Integer room);

*Error*

Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.

Comment: Don't tag spam.

Comment: Hello b, try with this `@Select("select * from func_get_available_room(?1, ?2,ARRAY[ ?3::Integer ], ?4)")
`

Comment: List<RoomAvailable> getAvailableRoom(String in, String out, List<Object> type , Integer room); I have this list is correct?

Comment: @PisithOscar You use MyBatis, right?

Comment: @sovannarithcheav yes

Comment: `@Select("select * from func_get_available_room(#{in},#{out}, #{type},#{room})")` and try use `@Param("type") List<Integer> type` ...

Comment: I got this error too : Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.